# How to change 8-gray level to 32 - gray level (GLCM) using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, glcm

I want to change 8-gray level to 32 gray level, i have tried to use 8-gray level in my image, but the value is  like this:

[image: here is the result]

so I want to try use 32-gray level:

[image: this is my image]

this is my code

```
I = imread('001 A.png');
gray = rgb2gray(I);
offsets = [0 1;-1 1;-1 0;-1 -1];
[GLCMS,SI] = graycomatrix(gray,'Of', offsets);  
stats = graycoprops(GLCMS,
{'contrast','homogeneity','correlation','energy'});
```

maybe anyone can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: The image is blank. That's probably why you're not getting any cooccurrences.

Comment: all the images I use is like that, so I want to try to use 32 levels on my image, maybe you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Set `Numlevel` to 32

```
I = imread('001 A.png');
gray = rgb2gray(I);
offsets = [0 1;-1 1;-1 0;-1 -1];
[GLCMS,SI] = graycomatrix(gray, 'Of', offsets, 'Numlevel', 32);  
stats = graycoprops(GLCMS, {'contrast','homogeneity','correlation','energy'});
```